# Can retagging prevent closing ..?

Tags: support, dupehammer

I just had my [very first dupehammer excersise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36139940/1407478). I was wondering, since I have earned the privilege on the jquery tag - is the question reopened if OP (or someone else) retag the question and remove the jquery tag?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess it will be still closed, just that it's in the reopen queue from the edit

Comment: dup hammered to a non-dupe and corrected tags to answer the question.

Comment: What is the irony in that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a question is not going to be reopened just because it's been retagged.

Comment: Du you dare to POC on the  question in subject ..? :)

Comment: @davidkonrad You could have done it yourself, but sure.  Demo provided.

Comment: you are right ..